# iTunes Connect and Apple Developer Portal

Tags: iphone

I have written an app for a client and I want to create ad hoc builds and submit to app store using his accounts.

Does he need to create an iTunes Connect AND a Apple Developer account - aren't they connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paid Apple developer account is the main thing..(it lets you access to iOS dev centre..sdk betas..etc)

ITunes Connect require some more documents and agreeing to term conditions so that you can build and deploy your apps too.

Both are required...payment will be for Apple developer only.

Comment: Should I add the app through Connect or though Xcode to the app store though?  And if its connect should the non-tech client do it or what would you suggest?

Comment: register the app on iTunes connect..(screenshots..description.and other things)  ..actual upload of the app(binary) is done through Xcode.....uploading can only be done from the person who has mac(Xcode ruins on mac) ...so  it depends..both can upload..